# Jerky transition after the login screen

Tags: windows-7, aero, login-screen

I have a clean install of Windows 7 Professional x64. After I type my password at the logon screen, the blue background is supposed to fade away smoothly and show the desktop, but on my machine the transition is jerky.

I have an ATI graphics card and the Catalyst 10.2 drivers. What can I do to make the transition more smooth?

Thanks!

Comment: Update with a list of parts? Performance is impossible to determine unless we have the full specs of your machine. This includes model/manufacture of parts like the CPU, Motherboard, Memory, Video Card, and Hard Drive(s). Is this a machine built by a company like Dell or Gateway? Did you make it yourself. Details are key to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

We really can't tell you without having more technical details about your system, but it sounds off hand that your system is likely not powerful enough to fully support Aero.  But as I say, that's just a guess.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the hardware since I have 7.6 at the windows performance mark, the catalyst drivers are compatible with Windows 7 64bit, so i really don't understand.

After the logon screen, everything are fine.

Comment: I change to Windows Basic, still the same problem !!
Maybe something to do with the monitor ? I have a Samsung F2380

Comment: Actually, hardware has everything to do with performance. When you log in, there is a list of things that must happen to get you to the desktop. The windows performance score does mean something, but it's useless when it comes to troubleshooting. List what you are using and we can help, blame the software and you'll have to figure it out on your own.